# deform a flat grid/mesh in opengl

Tags: algorithm, opengl-es, graph-algorithm

i need to deform a mesh/grid (only in 2d z remains same) in opengl

by deform i mean user will use mouse or touch and drag a particular vertice and rest will follow

here is a link ( http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/3432/2d_surface_deformation.php) that explains exactly what i need but it looks too hard for me to implement myself, can anyone point me to a resource or suggest a simpler way (by using some graphics library or something) it would be great

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with the graphics library of your choice, OpenGL or any other. It is a matter of physics simulation so you need a physics library. Look at [this one](http://box2d.org/).